# Is there a property that makes Ionicons have some press feedback?

Tags: react-native, expo, ionicons

I'm using `Ionicons` from `@expo/vector-icons` in some parts of my application. I'm trying to ensure that all `pressable` elements in my UI have some sort of visual feedback. I checked the vector-icons API and didn't find any relevant properties but I just want to ensure I know the best way to achieve this.

My guess is that I would have to wrap all of the `<Ionicons />` in a `TouchableOpacity` or another component of its type, other than `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Is this correct? Is there a more direct way to achieve this? And is my suggestion the way to go?

I don't think code is relevant here, but here it is anyway:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const HeaderIcon = (props) => {
    return (
        <Ionicons
            style={styles.icon}
            name={props.name}
            color={props.color}
            onPress={() => {
                props.onPress()
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your icon component with [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight#onhideunderlay)

it has `underlayColor` property where you can pass color.

e.g

```
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress} underlayColor="red">
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Touch Here</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

and also have two other underlay callbacks such as `onShowUnderlay` and `onHideUnderlay` these callbacks can be used in different scenarios

Like `onShowUnderlay` you can change icon color or trigger any other function.